# Visual Studio: Diff for unsaved changes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, diff

**Can VS**, just like [VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_compare-dirty-file-with-version-on-disk), [ST](http://sublimetexttips.com/how-to-view-file-changes-in-a-git-style-diff/), [IntelliJ&Co](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/comparing-files.html#d72952e137) and via addons also [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/unsaved-changes) und [NPP](https://github.com/pnedev/compare-plugin), **show unsaved changes as diff**?

Comment: For others searching for this / SEO: Visual Studio Code, VSCode, Sublime Text, Notepad Plus Plus, Notepad++, "compare with saved"

Answer (score 0):

You asked the question first, so I won't flag this as a duplicate, that seems unfair for some reason and I don't know how the points work for that, but here is the answer:
[See unsaved changes in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874120/see-unsaved-changes-in-vscode)