# See unsaved changes in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when closing vscode, or a tab in it, I get a dialogue asking "Do you want to save the changes you made to `filename`?" However, the unsaved edits are actually from a previous session that was closed without such a query, probably when turning off the computer, so I can't remember if it was meaningful edits, or maybe just an accidental key-press, like a shortcut gone wrong; and doing `undo` to revisit the last edits doesn't work either.

My question: How can I see the diff between the saved version of a file, and the version in the editor window? I think it would be nicest just to have a "show diff" option in the dialogue, but for now I'm also happy with a command line diff command.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I'm using VSCode version 1.52.1 on MacOS and I had a similar problem that may not be the same problem, but I'm guessing it will work for you as well.

When you're in the Explorer view, in the upper left part of Explorer you have your "Open Editors." If that shows a dot to the left indicating that the buffer has changes in it, you can right click the file name and select "Compare with Saved." This will open another buffer to the side that will show you any unsaved changes.

To get rid of that window (it took me a bit to figure this out I'm sorry to say!), you can click the 'X' to the left of the extra buffer in "Open Editors."

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, that works! To close the comparison view you can also click on the x in the tab. They should really add this as a buttun in the close-confirmation-dialogue.

Comment: That's a really good idea, I agree with you.

Comment: They should add the "compare with saved" to the context menu when you right click the editor tab. I don't keep that "Open Editors" panel open because the tabs are basically the same list.

Comment: @ADJenks Good luck requesting the feature! Here's how I imagine it'll go: "Thanks for your request — let's put it to a vote! \*60 days pass\* It looks like no one voted on your request. Closing. Didn't you run an ad-campaign? Well, better luck next time!"

Answer (score 21):

A few bright notes for the keyboard players out there:

- The command you are asking about has a default shortcut. Unless you've applied a keyboard map extension, the <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> arpeggio opens the very same diff view between the active and saved versions of the current file. The default shortcut to close an editor tab (be it the diff or a file or anything at all) is <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>.
- The command, like any command in VSCode, is also accessible via the <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> command dropdown (on Linux, <kbd>F1</kbd> opens it too). Start typing e.g. `compa sav` (it saves your keyboard wear and tear to shorten words to a prefix which is unambiguous enough), and the list will shrink dynamically to just a few commands.   Yours is *File: Compare Active File with Saved*. When it's close to the top enough, navigate the list of commands with the down arrow and execute it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. As a bonus, you may click on the little gear to the right of the command currently highlighted in the list and redefine its shortcut, if you use it very often and prefer a chord shortcut to the default arpeggio one. Sorry, there does not seem to be a shortcut in lieu of the gear click. If there is, please let me know!

- But if you really, really want to right-click on the filename in the *Open Editors* view of the *Explorer* sidebar, you can open that view directly with, you guessed it, a shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>. And if you change your mind on a dime right at this moment, or realize that you in fact never had a mouse to do the right-click in the first place, use <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> to drop down the "right-click menu", properly called the *context menu*, which you navigate with arrows and execute with <kbd>Enter</kbd> (that's kinda a common theme, as you probably noticed). This works mostly anywhere the right-click does.
- While in the *Open Editors* view, to switch to an editor file tab, move the selection to the desired file. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to bring the file into view but stay in the *Open Editors* view, or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring the file into view and shift the keyboard focus to it. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> brings focus back to the editor from any view in the *Explorer* sidebar. The same shortcut moves focus to the *Explorer* sidebar from the editor.

Happy ♬ k'boarding ♬!

Comment: @user313032, thanks for spotting the incorrect shortcut, and sorry that I restored your emphatic reduplication copyedit part. I do appreciate your taking time to fix the main and the most important incorrect information issue. I also added a comment to the markup with an explanation and a supporting reference.

Comment: I only removed one of the "really"s because of the condition that edits have to change at least 6 characters

Answer (score 9):

ctrl+shift+P (or command+shift+P on mac) and fuzzy search for "compare changes with saved files"

Comment: I think now it says "Compare Active File with Saved"

Comment: I find this easier than remember which window to rightclick in or keyboard shortcuts