# How to see unsaved *lines* in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Working with VS Code, there's a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874120/see-unsaved-changes-in-vscode) to see *every* detail in changed lines and original text.

However, sometimes I would like just to see quickly ***which*** lines are changed from the saved file, with a colored mark in the gutter, as it happens with some other editors.

Is it possible without much hassle?

Comment: look in your settings, you must have switched it off, because it is default behavior for files in SCM (git)